# No boot device found after disabling legacy mode from BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, bios, uefi

I am using HP 15-n215tu.

I want to install Windows 8 in UEFI mode currently it is running on legacy mode.

I tried to update BIOS but after update asap it restarts again it shifts to legacy mode. So, I switched to USB install but after disabling legacy mode from BIOS it restarts again and says no OS installed on hard disk. After that I went to boot from devices(pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>) but it does not show any boot device and later on when I checked into BIOS in UEFI mode it shows no INTERNAL HARD DISK but below it there is legacy mode which shows INTERNAL HARD DISK.

I have created USB using rufus and read many tutorials but nothing helped.

Comment: Are you trying to install the 32 or 64 bit version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after disabling legacy mode from BIOS it restarts again and says 
>   no OS installed on hard disk.

That is what it should do. If you disable legacy mode for this in the firmware and only allow EFI boots then it needs something to boot from which is not legacy. If all what is on the disk is MBR&old_windows then there is no EFO bootable option.

What you want to do is:

1. Make sure you backup any document which you want to keep. (Restore settings to legacy if needed to access this).
2. Create a bootable pen drive. GPT/FAT/windows install files/the boot.efi in the right place.  Not sure if windows 8 does this correctly by default, for windows 7 I stall needed to move files around so it could find the right bootloader.
3. Configure the EFI firmware for normal EFI operations (e.g. no legacy CSM boot).
4. Insert the USB pendrive from step 2 and then power on the laptop. You should be able to boot from it.
5. Wipe the old disk completely. (Wipe old MBR structure. E.g. shift-F10 diskpart clean).
6. Reboot and boot from the pendrive again. Install on the harddisk, which windows should partition with things like EFI system partition, /boot partition and the main OS partition. Do not try this manuall or follow guide from Microsoft since these seem to conflict with what the windows installer expects.

Comment: I think bootx64.efi was missing from efi/boot (from USB), after putting it into the place now it does show boot device but after few sec it gives error: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xn2qu.jpg (check the pic) everything is same except the error code is : 0xc0000359

Comment: Thank you I just needed a new windows after enlightenment from your idea.